# A restriction of a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $T\in\mathcal{D}'\left(\left(-1,-1\right)\right)$
be a distribution on $\left(-1,1\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let
$G$ be the restriction of $T$ to $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right).$
Prove that there exist continuous functions $f_{0},\ldots,f_{m}\in C\left(\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]\right)$
such that 
$$
G=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\left(f_{k}\right),
$$
as distributions on $\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: How far have you come yourself? Any ideas?

Comment: I have no idea. I read this in a book, it makes me stunned.

Comment: This is one of the main property of distributions. From the definition of continuity of $T$ there exists functions $C,m$ such that $\forall \varphi \in C^\infty_c([a,b])$ then $|\langle T,\varphi \rangle| \le C_{a,b}\sum_{k \le m_{a,b}} \|\varphi^{(k)}\|_\infty$. $\ \ m_{a,b}$ is by definition the order of the restriction of $T$ to $C^\infty_c([a,b])$. Note the order of $T$ is $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} m_{-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon}$ which doesn't have to be finite.

Comment: How can we see our conclusion from what you 've written? I agree with your claim so far. But how do we show the existence of continuous functions $f_{0},...,f_{m}$?

Comment: Assume $T$ has order $0$ and is compactly supported on $[a,b]$. Do  you see that $\langle  T, \phi \rangle$ is now well-defined for any $\phi$ continuous ? Let $\Phi(x) = \int_a^x \phi(t)dt$. What can you say of the distribution defined by $\langle S,\phi \rangle = \langle T, \Phi \rangle$, do you see any way to ensure $S$ is represented by a bounded function ?

Comment: @reuns Could you give a hint to see that $S$ can be represented by a continuous function? Your suggestion is quite interesting.